# Custom Control DataBinding wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, dependency-properties

Currently implementing a custom control I would like to bind some Value directly from my viewModel without using xaml. 
I can do this:

```
<customControls:MyControl MyValue="{Binding ElementName=MyElem, Path=Text}">
<Textbox Text="{Binding Mytext}" />
```

But not:

```
<customControls:MyControl MyValue="{Binding MyText}">
```

The controls is defined in a template and inside the Control code my the MyProperty is defined as:

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty MyValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyValue", typeof(double), typeof(CustomOEE), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Double)20,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
   public double MyValue
   {
       get
       {
           return (double)GetValue(MyValueProperty);
       }
       set
       {
           SetValue(MyValueProperty, value);

       }
   }
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You are binding text to a property of type double and specifying two-way binding. Double to string will happen with ToString() but you can't automatically convert back. This post has some details on the conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178738/wpf-string-to-double-converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general answer, within a UserControl you bind just to the UserControl DependencyProperties and you do that with ElementName or RelativeSource binding and you should **never** set the DataContext within a UserControl.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc", 
         typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));

public string MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc
{
   get
   {
       return (string)GetValue(MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty);
   }
   set
   {
       SetValue(MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty, value);

   }
}
```

xaml

```
 <UserControl x:Name="myRealUC" x:class="MyUserControl">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myRealUC, Path=MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
 <UserControl>
```

If you do that you can easily use this Usercontrol in any view like:

```
<myControls:MyUserControl MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc="{Binding MyPropertyInMyViewmodel}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Making my control inherits from UserControl and Not Control and changing the binding solved everything.

Comment: Ok, I will do it :-). But I just have on more question pls: what is the xaml to use a style template in a ressource dictionnary for this control ?

Comment: i do not understand what you want, maybe you should create a new question with some more information