# Binding to DependancyProperty

Tags: wpf, mvvm

My XAML won't bind and I can't see why

Using MVVM, I have the following code in my MyView.xaml

```
<Expander Header="{Binding ThresholdName}" IsExpanded="False" >
    <properties:PropertiesVm Name="{Binding ThresholdName}" />
</Expander>
```

And this has a DataTemplate of MyViewModel.cs

As you can see, I'm using the ThresholdName twice. When I run my application, I can see the ThrehsoldName in the `Header` of the `Expander` indicating that the binding at this point is fine. The issue is binding to my "properties" object.

The Properties View is

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</Grid>
```

And the ViewModel(which inherits from `DependancyObject`) is

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(PropertiesVm));

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (Convert.ToString(GetValue(NameProperty))); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }
```

The error message I get is

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Time; DataItem=null; target element is 'PropertiesVm' (HashCode=6494098); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')

And within my Dictionary, I have set the DataTemplate as

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:PropertiesVm}">
    <view:PropertiesView />
</DataTemplate>
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181890/binding-in-wpf-style-causes-inexplicable-cannot-find-governing-frameworkelement) suggests adding `x:Name` but that didn't help

Why does the property `Name` in my Properties ViewModel never get set? Or can I only do this with a UserControl, binding to code behind?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916756/custom-control-databinding-wpf/29917351#29917351 check this if you want use UserControls with Dependency Properties

Comment: @blindmeis, thanks for this, i'ts great information but I'm not setting the DataContext in my userControl, It inherits it naturally from the parent I thought

Comment: and @blindmeis, the same issue persists...

Comment: the binding within your usercontrol with a DP should always have ElemenName Binding or RelativSource Binding. i prefer the first one. i dont see this in your xaml. and pls use Snoop if you have binding problems. you can check on runtime your Datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

You've got things a bit about face.

Your Expander content needs to bind to a property of your top level view model which exposes your instance of PropertiesVm. A bit like:

```
public class TopLevelVm
{
  public string ThresholdName { get; }
  public PropertiesVm Properties { get; }
}
```

Then your XAML could be like:

```
<Expander Header="{Binding ThresholdName}" Content="{Binding }" />
```

Then the DataTemplate will pick the same DataContext, and your DataTemplate could look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThresholdName}" />
    <!-- Do something with .Properties -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: If I did this, how would I have bound the Name property?

Comment: Yeah sorry...is your view model a FrameworkElement or a DepedencyObject?

Comment: ...updated my answer a little bit, think you just need to twist your model around a bit...