# WPF Databinding error on custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently getting the following error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'EthernetView' property not found on 'object' ''LabelTextBox' (Name='Root')'. BindingExpression:Path=EthernetView.SessionName; DataItem='LabelTextBox' (Name='Root'); target element is 'LabelTextBox' (Name='Root'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

when I bind data to a custom control like

```
<controls:LabelTextBox Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,5,10,0" LabelText="Name" Text="{Binding EthernetView.SessionName}" 
                                       TextWidth="175"  IsReadOnly="True" IsError="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

I am pretty sure I have my Dependency property on the object set up correctly

```
public partial class LabelTextBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return LblTextBox.Text; }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            LblTextBox.Text = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(LabelTextBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnTextPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelTextBox source = d as LabelTextBox;
        source.LblTextBox.Text = e.NewValue as string;
    }
}
```

The xaml for the custom control looks like

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.LabelTextBox"
             x:Name="Root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TextWidthColumn" Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="LeftLabel" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" Padding="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12"
                   Text="{Binding LabelText, ElementName=Root, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Border x:Name="TextBoxBorder" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="2" Background="#FAFAFAFA">
            <TextBox x:Name="LblTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1"  FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Text}"
                   TextChanged="LblTextBox_TextChanged" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler"/>
        </Border>
        <Image x:Name="ErrorImage" Grid.Column="2" Source="pack://application:,,,/Project;component/Images/RedX.ico" Height="12" Width="12"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="RightLabel" Grid.Column="3" Foreground="Black" Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12"
                   Text="{Binding LabelText, ElementName=Root, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code works properly at runtime, but I would like to clean up the output errors. Can anyone give me some insight on how to fix this error.

Comment: It means that your LabelTextBox DataContext does not include EthernetView, so you have to bind to relative source and find ancestor which has it. Its hard to answer it without seeing the viewmodel and how it is all wired up.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Properties looks like this (GetValue, SetValue!):

```
    public readonly static DependencyProperty IsBusyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(BusyControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value); }
    }
```

so yours is not right.

Comment: This may be the standard way of implementing the binding, but doing this in my code not only breaks the functionality where the binding doesn't work at all during runtime, it also breaks the text changed events

Comment: here is my general answer to UserControl DP Binding Problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916756/custom-control-databinding-wpf/29917351#29917351 your code mix up DP and INPC viewmodel stuff and codebehind events. pls add What you wanna achieve/how should it work  to your question.